# How to create a multiple line cell in pyplot table

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-table

Is it possible to use a multiple line cell in pyplot (Matplotlib) table ?
... or merge cells in pyplot table. Here an example :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
table1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
plt_table1=plt.table(cellText=table1, rowLabels=['Line 1\n and stuff', 'line 2'])
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Is it possible to use [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279807/matplotlib-table-with-double-headers) ?

Comment: Yes it is absolutely possible to use the idea from the linked question and answer. What problem do you encounter?

Comment: I wanted to know if simpler solutions exist, of tools more dedicated to display graphs, texts and tables. The plt.table seems to me a bit poor.

Comment: Well, not within matplotlib. Outside of matplotlib there are of course many options to create and display tables. One common option is to use HTML.